# Is BJT amplifier a viable option if the design needs to be replicated without calibration?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, power-electronics, manufacturing

||*Sorry for messing this up the first time. This is my first post ever in a technical forum. Need to pick up the ways of the crowd. Thanks for all the feedback and help. Well appreciated*||

I intend to design a product targeting the rural market. As each penny counts for my customers, I need to optimize both the design and manufacturing process to be as cost effective as possible. The design involves a boost converter which should look something like this except for the following.

a. Input will be a 12V battery

b. The controller will be UC3843/5, a variant of that used in the schematic

c. The load will be a series LED string (open circuit or constant current 150mA with 20V/40V/60V).

[image: Boost converter]

I am experimenting all the options and one of them involves replacing the controller IC with a 555 timer PWM generator. In such a design, I need to amplify the voltage across a current sense resistor like R10 with a gain of about 30. I could either use an op-amp configuration or a BJT amplifier to do this. BJT looks cheap and may reduce my BOM cost. But to my knowledge, if the gain of a BJT transistor varies from piece to piece then I need to add a calibration process which increases my manufacturing cost.

So is there anyway I could use a BJT amplifier circuit in a design that can be replicated without needing to calibrate it each time.

Comment: What voltage. What gain? Application detail useful. What are you amplifying? - eg sound or a DC level or an on off switch or ??? Decent detail will allow an optimum solution to be provided. I and a number of others here would be extremely pleased to provide assistance to make the best possible circuit for your application **but** KNOWING WHAT THE APPLICATION IS MAKES THE TASK **VASTLY** EASIER. I have substantial experience in squeezing cost out of low cost bottom end circuits. Help us help you. email me privately if you wish (see jmy profile for address) BUT doing it here is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have made some edits. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Much better - getting there :-). I assume V1 & V3 are DC? 12V or ? Battery? From long ago memory the 3842 needs about 12V to start and somewhat less to run (originally intended for offline use). | What LED string voltage typical ? (~!= 3V x N for N LEDs for white) | Look at MC34063 - as cheap as 555 under 10 cents and maybe 5 US cents in 1000 up vol in China) and more versatile. Not efficient at low Vin but OKish at ~= 12v.  || LED string REALLY REALLY should be current driven so needs a sense resistor for feedback.  | 34063 has 1.2 V Vfb but this camn be lowered with minimal circuitry.....

Comment: ... For amplifier for Isense (if needed) ok at "long tailed pair" (LTP). | IF you have a set voltage or current then you don't need an amp but a comparator and LTP is excellent. Also OK as amplifier - it is gain element in opamps | FWIW Single BJT stage has MAX gain of ~= 38 x V across Rcollector. eg if V_Rc = 5V gain max is 5 x 38 = 190.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify the voltage across the shunt resistor or the accuracy required, but anyway the gain can be stabilized by use of negative feedback such as emitter degeneration. For this to work you need to design the circuit to have excessive gain and remove the excess with negative feedback. For example, if you need a gain of 100 you might design a circuit capable of a gain of 10,000 typically and apply negative feedback to reduce it to 100, so even if the gain varies from 5,000 to 20,000 because of the transistors, the (closed loop) circuit gain will vary less than +/-1%. This will also stabilize the circuit against temperature changes, since resistors are generally very stable compared to transistor beta.

That may be all that is required if it is an AC circuit. If it's a DC circuit then offset voltage means that an op-amp is going to be better- you'd need differential transistors (perhaps matched and thermally coupled) and a complex circuit, and it still would not be very good.

Op-amps (at the lowest end) need not cost much more than a BJT. 1-2 cents each in a quad package. Probably cheaper than a MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have edited the question to bring more clarity. But as per your advice it seems I will be better off with an Op-amp since this is a DC circuit. Isn't it?